# Terraform scripted AWS CodePipeline fails on Deploy stage with InternalError

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

I'm attempting to use AWS CodePipeline to deploy an app to an EC2 instance using CodeDeploy agent, but it's failing with this frustratingly vague
"InternalError":

[image: CodePipeline error message]

I can't find any other meaningful error.

I'm using terraform to define the CodePipeline.  This is the "Deploy" section:

```
stage {
  name = "Deploy"

  action {
    name            = "Deploy"
    category        = "Deploy"
    owner           = "AWS"
    provider        = "CodeDeploy"
    input_artifacts = ["buildOut"]
    run_order        = 1
    version         = "1"

    configuration = {
      ApplicationName    = aws_codedeploy_app.my-codedeploy-app.id
      DeploymentGroupName = aws_codedeploy_deployment_group.my-codedeploy-group.id
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your `appspec.yml`?

Comment: I've had similar caused by issues with the agent on the EC2 - latest version? Is the agent running? What do the agent logs show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two small problems with your deployment definition.

1. **ApplicationName** should reference *app.name*, not *app.id*
2. **DeploymentGroupName** should reference *deployment_group_name*, not *group.id*

Try this:

```
stage {
  name = "Deploy"
  action {
    name            = "Deploy"
    category        = "Deploy"
    owner           = "AWS"
    provider        = "CodeDeploy"
    input_artifacts = ["buildOut"]
    run_order        = 1
    version         = "1"
    configuration = {
      ApplicationName    = aws_codedeploy_app.my-codedeploy-app.name  // This should be name, not id
      DeploymentGroupName = aws_codedeploy_deployment_group.my-codedeploy-group.deployment_group_name  // this should be deployment_group_name, not id
    }
  }
}
```